# Disable Check booking availability from listify theme wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

how i can disable Check booking availability and send direct user to make payment in listify wordpress theme. now it send a confirm mail then user can make payment but i want it directly how can i do this any one help please

Answer (score 1):

Use this in function.php

```
 function manage_available_gateways( $gateways ) {
    unset($gateways['wc-booking-gateway']);
    return $gateways;
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'manage_available_gateways' );
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the asker's problem, it would be preferable to explain how it works - you can do so by [edit]ing your answer.